# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll;Additional information: Cannot find column []

Tags: c#

I created two forms:

Form 1 contains:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class frPlanMain : Form
    {

        public SearchWindow frm2;

        public frPlanMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frPlanMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) ***//Loads data from a certain path in GridView***
        {
            string constr = "Provider = MicroSoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + locTBox.Text + ";Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=NO;\";";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + shTBox.Text + "$]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dGVPlan.DataSource = dt;
            new SearchWindow(this).Show();
            this.Show();
         }
}
}
```

And Form 2 :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class SearchWindow : Form
    {
        public frPlanMain refTofrPlanMain;

        public SearchWindow(frPlanMain f) 
        {
            refTofrPlanMain = f;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Searches the value in textbox in Form2 in dataGridView in Form1.
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = "[NrFir] like '%" + searchTBoxW.Text + "%'"; //<-- Error located here.
            refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource = bs;
        }
    }
}
```

When i click on the search button I receive the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll;
>   Additional information: Cannot find column [NrFir].

I have created columns in the DataGridView that referances to F1-F22 from a .xls file. NrFir is the column that i want to search in.

How can i fix the error ???

Comment: remove the [] around NrFir

Comment: [BindingSource.Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) has another syntax than sql. As @PedroG.Dias commented, do not use `[` and `]` around field/column name.

Comment: It did not solve my problem. Still the same error messange appeared, but for some wierd reason it displayed it in [] even if i removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `DataTable` you are using as data-source, hasn't column-name. So, it's getting automatic column-names. Actually, your column-names from sheet, are assuming as a data-row. So, you need a cleanup here:

```
    private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string constr = "Provider = MicroSoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + locTBox.Text + ";Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=NO;\";";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + shTBox.Text + "$]", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        CleanupDataTable(dt); // call the cleanup here, before binding dgv to dt
        dGVPlan.DataSource = dt;
        new SearchWindow(this).Show();
        //this.Show(); why you are calling show() here?
    }

    private void CleanupDataTable(DataTable dt) {
        if(dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            return;
        var headerRow = dt.Rows[0];
        var columns = headerRow.ItemArray;
        // 1. give the right column names
        for(int i = 0, l = columns.Length; i < l; i++)
            dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = columns[i].ToString();
        // 2. remove the header row from the result
        dt.Rows.Remove(headerRow);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** More details:

When you create headers in xls file and load it into a `DataTable`, the header row in your xls, won't be header in `DataTabe` too. So, your `DataTable`'s headers would be F1, F2, .... So, if you want your `DataTable` has same headers as xls file, you have to do it manually. So, you need to follow these steps:

1. Load xls file into a `DataTable`
2. Get the first row of `DataTable` (which is the header row actually)
3. Read values from first row and edit `DataTable`'s headers names column by column
4. Remove the header row from `DataTable`

Comment: So if the column where i want to search is called NrFir, i should replace instead of the ColumnName in dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = columns[i].ToString(); ?

Comment: I added column headers, and i i told them to get data from F1 - F22 and deleted the header from the .xls file, should i keep the header in the .xls ?

Comment: Yes you should keep headers in sheet. Just do what I did and you will get result.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code provided and i still get a error. Was there something i should modify in the code provided ?  An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ColumnName is required when it is part of a DataTable.

Comment: According to your previous comments, seems you deleted header from .xls file. Did you? Put break-point at line `dGVPlan.DataSource = dt;` and see what's headers' names in `dt`.

Comment: Do the headers in the .xls have to match the ones in the DataGridView, DataTable ? I recopied them in the .xls

Comment: The headers in the .xls and the ones in the DataGridView, DataTable differ. But i referenced the headers in the DataGridView, DataTable to columns from F1 to F22. The one i want to filter in is F1 = NrFir

Comment: See the update please. And to your previous comment: So you need to search against `F1` not `NrFir`.

Comment: It did not work ... or i do not know how to do that :( . Is there any other way i could do this . Or would you be willing to have a look at the code if i send it to you ?

Comment: @StefanSiman OK. seems there is a little break in code ): yeh sure. send me the code to javad[dot]d[dot]amiry [at] gmail. and don't forget to send your xls sample

Comment: Did you recieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Javad_Amiry. I found out what the problem was on my side. It was due tot the fact that i added the columns from the design view of the data grid.
When i added the columns by code in the DataTable, the filter worked on column NrFir.